# Import javascript text editor gui to my web app

Tags: javascript, html, jsp, tomcat, jakarta-ee

As it is done for example by Microsoft 365 or Google Docs, I want to embed a text editor frame on my website.

I just want some really basics functions, as add title, bold/italic text and image adding function (upload on server then add it to the document) and finally get an input as an html code instead of a docx or odt to push it into my database.

The tricky part is that I need to add a custom header/footer on each page. The user should not be able to edit them. But they have to be already there when the user will open the document into my web text editor to get a real-time render framework and to be able to know accurately when his document will have a page break.

I am using Tomcat 8.5 with Javascript and even Bootstrap and Jquery.

First of all I was looking for a Java library to do that, like the [OpenOffice.org UNO api](http://www.openoffice.org/api/) but it seems like I have to fully create my own interface which is not what I am looking for.

Then I found [WebODF](http://webodf.org/) but It doesn't seem to have a function to export as html or add header/footer (but it's really close to what I need)

I though Google released a Google Docs api to embed a text editor frame easily on our website but I only found a [Google Drive api](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/about-sdk) which allows you to create websites working which google drive.

Can you, please, indicate me a good library or website frame I can import to my project ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is what you are looking for they are called WYSIWYG Editor, I have included one, but can find a lot just by Google searching it: 
*I just included this, because it is free.* 
 - [Editor](https://www.froala.com/wysiwyg-editor)

Comment: Thanks to you by googling I found a lot of stuff like Quill or summernote. I think some of them will do the work. Thanks !

Comment: No problem any time!